# how can i select an element in a template within a web component using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, templates, element

I'm having the hardest time selecting the ".recipe-type-menu-container" within the template in this component I built. I've tried using:

```
const container = typeofRecipe_template.content.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu-container");
```

but I keep getting an undefined error message. I'm trying to do all this with vanilla JS.

```
export class TypeofRecipe extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }  // end of constructor()

    connectedCallback(){
        var container;  
        var typeofRecipe_template = document.createElement('template');
            typeofRecipe_template.innerHTML = `

                <div class="recipe-type-menu-container" >
                    <div class="recipe-type-menu-row"></div>
                    <div class="recipe-type-menu-row"></div>  
                </div> <!---recipe-type-menu-container ->
`;
        const container = typeofRecipe_template.content.querySelector(".recipe-type-menu-container");   
        this.parentNode.appendChild(typeofRecipe_template.content.cloneNode(true));
    };
}
```

Comment: The last line `this.parentNode.appendChild( ...` should definitely be written before the `const container = ...`. 

After you've added  `typeofRecipe_template` into the DOM, you can now select the container `document.querySelectorAll(".recipe-type-menu-container")[0]`

Comment: Hey thanks for responding.  That was a great help...thank you